Urdu dataset Required
I want to do research on text prediction but dataset which I am using is only 140000 words,I want larger dataset for model training.
Anyone please help to find out Urdu dataset which is larger in size and can be used in text prediction task.
I have tried to search lots of dataset but didn't find any suitable for my project
